# Running Jenkins controller and agent with docker compose - is it possible?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

The Jenkins controller and Jenkins agent are supposedly able to be run in Docker;

Under Jenkins' official installation instructions, **Docker** is the first option listed:

- [User Handbook -> Installing Jenkins -> Docker](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/)

They also appear to have an [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/ssh-agent) for a Jenkins agent that can used by a dockerized Jenkins controller.
I learned about this docker image from [this blog article](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/how-to-install-and-run-jenkins-with-docker-compose) describing how to install a Jenkins controller and agent using docker compose.

The instructions at that link needed some tweaking. For example the the "built-in node" works if the `jenkins` container has `/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` in the `volumes:` section.

The trouble is getting the agent container to work at all. I had to manually install git in the official image, and no matter what I try it seems unable to access the host's instance of the docker service.

Here's my current `docker-compose.yml` file (with credentials omitted)

```
version: "3"

networks:
  jenkins:

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 3102:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /var/my-data-folder/jenkins/certs:/certs/client
      - /var/my-data-folder/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
  jenkins-agent:
    # image: jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11
    build: ./jenkins-agent
    container_name: jenkins-agent
    privileged: true
    user: root
    container_name: agent
    expose:
      - 22
    environment:
      - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=...
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

I get the following error:

```
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I think this is because the `jenkins` user doesn't have permission to do this. I tried adding a docker group in the container and `usermod -aG docker jenkins`. I tried adding a jenkins user to the host and `usermod -aG docker jenkins`. I didn't expect either to work, and neither did.

What am I doing wrong?